# Is 她在2015年被选为《自然》杂志年度十大人物 grammatical (does it need a 之一)?

Tags: grammar

> **她在2015年被选为《自然》杂志年度十大人物**，在2016年当选美国国家工程院院士，2017年获得世界杰出女科学家奖，同年升任斯坦福大学化学工程学院院长，成为斯坦福大学首个华人女院长。2021年，她当选美国文理科学院院士，也成为中国科学院外籍院士。
> <sub>[下一位获得诺贝尔奖的华人，可能是她？](https://news.sina.com.cn/c/2022-10-05/doc-imqqsmrp1553219.shtml), October 2022.</sub>

The first clause of the above paragraph reminds of similar structures which are considered 语病.  The canonical example is 她是四大美女之一 (correct) vs. 她是四大美女 (incorrect); the grammar doesn't behave the same as 她是老师.  I'm not sure if the clause in bold above involves a "missing 之一" grammar error; it looks like it to me, but 被选为 might be different to 是.

**Question**: Is 她在2015年被选为《自然》杂志年度十大人物 grammatical (does it need a 之一)?

Comment: I think it needs a 之一, because 为 indicates equivalence, and she is not all ten people at once. Alternatively, I think this also works: 她在2015年被选 *进*《自然》杂志年度十大人物.

Answer (score 2):

年度十大人物 is a ***title*** or an ***award*** here. If you add 之一, and then take the phrase literally(not as a title).

Answer (score 2):

> 她在2015年被选为《自然》杂志年度十大人物

"《自然》杂志年度十大人物" (Nature Magazine's top ten people of the year) is the award title,

"《自然》杂志年度十大人物之一" would be incorrect as an award title but grammatical as a noun phrase meaning "one of the Nature Magazine's top ten people of the year"

Since this title is given to ten people, 被选为 doesn't sound accurate, a better term would be 她在2015年**入选**《自然》杂志年度十大人物

Similarly:

流行榜前十 is an award title awarded to ten songs

登上流行榜前十 is more accurate than 奪得流行榜前十

奪得流行榜前十首位 would be correct as a verb phrase

Answer (score 0):

A simple understanding of similar issues is that "之一" need not be used when recounting a person's honor or personal experience.

Of course, the grammar of these two sentences is correct, but the usage scenarios are slightly different.

Answer (score -1):

不用“之一”，语法好，都好了！

Sounds like a high-flyer, can you get me her telephone number?? :)